# New car - a lot of smoke from exhaust

Tags: exhaust, kia, smoke

I got my new car today from the dealership, and while driving home I noticed there is quite a bit of smoke coming of the exhaust, to the point of blocking my rear window visibility. Only happens when I accelerate and the colour is white from what I could see. It's quite cold here now and I thought maybe it's just water vapor, but no other car around me produced the same smoke.

Is this a normal occurence for a new engine or should I contact the dealer?

EDIT: the car in question is a Kia Ceed with 1.6 GDi petrol engine.

EDIT2: I took the car to dealer and it turned out the cooling system was actually filled quite past the max level, and it didn't remove the excess like it was supposed to do (or so I was told) - after fix the issue is resolved.

Comment: Does it smell sweet?

Comment: I don't know really, as I can't accelerate and stand behind the car at the same time :) When the engine is on neutral, or when maintaining constant speed, there is no smoke, only when accelerating.

Comment: does it persist after warm up?

Comment: @agentp This happened when engine reached operating temperature, when it was cold there was no smoke.

Comment: This sound very wrong. Check your coolant level. If its out as I suspect it will be, I wouldn't even fill it but call the dealer and have them tow it in.

Comment: Currently there is a snowstorm here, but I'll check it the first thing in the morning.

Comment: If this is a brand new car, take it back to the dealership. It sounds like either there's a problem with coolant getting into the combustion chamber, or the direct injection isn't working correctly. Either way, this is something for the dealership to take care of under warranty.

Comment: the explanation you were given doesn't make sense (assuming it was actually coming out the exhaust in the first place).  Glad you got it fixed in any case.